# display words between semi colons with sed or awk

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I would like to display fields  first and third in file full on entries like the one below

```
first;second;third;four
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply with `cut` command:

```
cut -d';' -f1,3 file
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `awk` could help you here.

```
awk -F";" '{print $1,$3}' Input_file
```